# .htaccess not working even tho the code is right

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm sure my code is right but for some reason, its not working.

The .htaccess file is in the root html directory.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.gov.qa [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.gov.qa/$1 [L,R=301]

# END WordPress
```

Is it something with apache?

Comment: No idea of that "code is right"... How should we tell if you don't say what you actually want to achieve...

Comment: Does that http server consider dynamic configuration files _at all_ ? Is it configured to do so? How?